# Split elements in vector to different column with fread

Tags: r, data.table, fread

Assume I have very big TSV file with over 20M lines that look like this:

```
    a b {"condition1":["ABC"], "condition3":false, "condition4":4000}
    c c {"condition1":["BBB"],"condition2":true}
```

I need it to look like:

```
     Var1 Var2 Condition1 Condition2 Condition3 Condition4
     a    b    ABC        NA         FALSE      4000
     c    c    BBB        TRUE       NA         NA
```

I tried the following code, but it is:
a. inefficient
b. does not work

anyway out-of-the-shelf solution to separate the 3rd column while reading?

```
     dt<-fread(input = ifilename, header = T,encoding = "UTF-8" )
     output<-dt[,c("filter")]  #assume the third column named "filter"
     fwrite(x = output,file = "./DB/filter.csv",)
     filter.db<-fread(input ="./DB/filter.csv",fill=T)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `TRUE` and not `true` or `True`? That data looks a lot like JSON or python dictionary and there are many tools to parse those objects (for instance the `jsonlite` package).

Comment: You are right, I edited it.

Comment: one thing at a time! 1. read data. 2. column split/json parse 3. add back to data.frame

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
library(data.table)
library(jsonlite)

to_add <- rbindlist(lapply(dt$V3, function(x) setDT(fromJSON(x))), fill = TRUE)
setcolorder(to_add, sort(names(to_add)))

dt[, names(to_add) := to_add][, V3 := NULL][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    V1 V2 condition1 condition2 condition3 condition4
> 1:  a  b        ABC         NA      FALSE       4000
> 2:  c  c        BBB       TRUE         NA         NA
> ```

---

Used data:

```
dt <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "c"),
                     V2 = c("b", "c"),
                     V3 = c("{\"condition1\":[\"ABC\"], \"condition3\":false, \"condition4\":4000}",
                            "{\"condition1\":[\"BBB\"],\"condition2\":true}")),
                .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. However, it looks like sparsing 23M rows after I load them is quite costly, in terms of time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*nix tools may be faster in this case, as the json parsers in R are a bit slow in my testing.

```
> library(data.table)
> aTbl = fread(cmd="cat foo.txt | grep -P -o '^\\w+\\s+\\w+'", header=F)
> aTbl
   V1 V2
1:  a  b
2:  c  c

> bTbl = fread(cmd="cat foo.txt | grep -P -o '[{].*$' | jq -r '[ .condition1[], .condition2, .condition3, .condition4 ] | @csv'", header=F)
> bTbl
    V1   V2    V3   V4
1: ABC   NA FALSE 4000
2: BBB TRUE    NA   NA

> setnames(aTbl, c('Var1', 'Var2'))
> setnames(bTbl, c('Condition1', 'Condition2', 'Condition3', 'Condition4'))

> cTbl = cbind(aTbl, bTbl)
> cTbl
   Var1 Var2 Condition1 Condition2 Condition3 Condition4
1:    a    b        ABC         NA      FALSE       4000
2:    c    c        BBB       TRUE         NA         NA
>
```